# Metrics on the 3-sphere with knotted geodesics

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, knot-theory, geodesics

According to answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180482/simple-closed-geodesics-in-mathbbs3-manifold) every metrics on $S^3$ admits a simple closed geodesic. Given a knot (or link) $K$, it's also quite simple to build a metric on $S^3$ such that $K$ is a geodesic (for some parametrisation).

> Is there a Riemannian metric on $S^3$ such that *all* its simple closed geodesics are topologically knotted?

Comment: Perhaps relevant is: http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9906021 where Etnyre and Grist establish existence of analytic contact flows on the three-sphere whose solution curves realize every knot type.  Geodesic flow on the three-sphere however is a contact flow on  a two-sphere bundle OVER the three-sphere so is a different matter ... somehow feels easier to me.  (? but is it?)

Comment: This feels a strange conjecture, because contrapositively you are asking whether, in some metric, *every unknot* is has intrinsic curvature.

Comment: Then I go ahead and calculate Euler-Lagrange equations for the action functional $\int \langle \nabla_X X, \nabla_X X\rangle dt $, and indeed there are Riemann curvature terms as well as $\nabla_X^3 X$ terms...